# Implementation of Arduino F() macro

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to understand what the F() macro in Arduino actually does with PGMEM and RAM and what are the runtime implications. Can someone point me at the file that defines this macro?

Comment: I *really* wish they didn't close the [arduino stackexchange beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino) after only 16 days. This would have been a perfect candidate. It's like Firefly all over again.

Comment: @IAmNaN check again. (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be an older version, but one place where it is defined is `Wstring.h` as in [here](http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/wp-content/images//avr-gcc-4.7.0/WString.h).

You can find it yourself: if you installed Arduino you can search the installation directory. `WString.h` should be in `hardware\arduino\cores\arduino\`