# Is there a minimum string length for F() to be useful?

Tags: arduino

Is there a limit for short strings where using the [`F()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597437/arduino-f-what-does-it-actually-do) macro brings more RAM overhead then saving?

For (a contrived) example:

```
Serial.print(F("\n"));
Serial.print(F("Hi"));
Serial.print(F("there!"));
Serial.print(F("How do you doyou how?"));
```

Would any one of those be more efficient without the `F()`?

I imagine it uses some RAM to iterate over the string and copy it from PROGMEM to RAM. I guess the question is: how much? Also, is heap fragmentation a concern here?

I'm looking at this purely from SRAM-conserving perspective.

Comment: F() macro is using for store string in flash memory, a complete documentation can be see to http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Memory. Depends how you want to use your string you can think about speed of access for flash or sram, for this you can see http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/221/what-can-i-do-if-i-run-out-of-flash-memory-or-sram.

Comment: @user1929959 The "complete documentation" has a full one sentence on the `F()` macro. I made clear that "I'm looking at this purely from SRAM-conserving perspective" in my question.

Comment: The only correct answer is *it depends* therefore this is off-topic: opinion based and too broad in that explaining how to profile this would take more than is allowed in the answer box.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Care to elaborate a bit? I think it's pretty deterministic, not opinion-based at all.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely SRAM-conserving perspective all of your examples are identical in that no SRAM is used. At run-time some RAM is used, but only momentarily on the stack. Keep in mind that calling `println()` (w/o any parameters) uses some stack/RAM.

For a single character it will take up less space in flash if a `char` is passed into `print` or `println`. For example:

```
Serial.print('\n');
```

The `char` will be in flash (not static RAM).

Using

```
Serial.print(F("\n"));
```

will create a string in flash memory that is two bytes long (newline char + null terminator) and will additionally pass a pointer to that string to `print` which is probably two bytes long.

Additionally at runtime, using the F macro will result in two fetches ('\n' and the null terminator) from flash. While fetches from flash are fast, passing in a `char` results in zero fetches from flash, which is a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any minimum size of the string to be useful. If you look at how the outputting is implemented in Print.cpp:

```C++
size_t Print::print(const __FlashStringHelper *ifsh)
{
  PGM_P p = reinterpret_cast<PGM_P>(ifsh);
  size_t n = 0;
  while (1) {
    unsigned char c = pgm_read_byte(p++);
    if (c == 0) break;
    n += write(c);
  }
  return n;
}
```

You can see from there that only one byte of RAM is used at a time (plus a couple of variables), as it pulls the string from PROGMEM a byte at a time. These are all on the stack so there is no ongoing overhead.

> I imagine it uses some RAM to iterate over the string and copy it from PROGMEM to RAM. I guess the question is: how much?

No, it doesn't as I showed above. It *outputs* a byte at a time. There is no copying (in bulk) of the string into RAM first.

> Also, is heap fragmentation a concern here?

No, the code does not use the heap.